# OpenCV Python creating bounding box or enclosing circle/polygon around scattered points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on object detection for collision avoidance using OpenCV Python on a small quad. First I need to detect objects using `Optical Flow Pyramid (LK)`(OpenCV) approach. I was able to track points on the image ROI as shown in the image [points tracked using opticalflow lk pyr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQAW6.jpg)

I need to create a bounding box or enclosing `convexHull` or some polygonal shape as shown below to show that these are the detected objects [red lines are which I drew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7CNd.jpg) . Ignoring isolated points, only points at certain distance to each other must be taken.

If any one could help me or provide me with your ideas it will be useful. 
If my question is not precise or to vast please let me know

Answer (score 1):

you can get minimum and maximum x,y values by looping through the cluster labels. and then can draw rectangles using those 4 points for each cluster. 
following code will help you.

```
ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(Z, 10, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

for i in label.ravel():
        x_values = []
        y_values = []

        count = Z[label.ravel()==i]
        for x,y in count:
            x_values.append(x)
            y_values.append(y)

            min_x = min(x_values)
            min_y = min(y_values)
            max_x = max(x_values)
            max_y=max(y_values)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (max_x, max_y), (min_x, min_y), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the bounding box draw a rectangle around p1(x_min, y_min) and p2(x_max, y_max), where x_min/max and y_min/max denote the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates of a point cluster.

So as you already have your points the first step is to form clusters of close points and get rid of outliers.

Please research **cluster analysis** to find out how to do this. I'm not willing to write a book here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis might give you a first idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem involves two steps:

1. You need to perform clustering over the key-points. I suggest taking a look at [scikit-learn clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).
2. Build a bounding rectangle or any other type convex envelope over each of the clusters.  For this `open CV` provides the function `BoundingRect`([link to the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect)) which provides the desired functionality: *The function calculates and returns the minimal up-right bounding rectangle for the specified point set.*